# JAXB unmarshalling inner class

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb, unmarshalling

Suppose I have some POJO class that can be stored in my DB.

```
class SomeClass {

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private Address address;

    //getters and setters

}
```

In this class, I have some inner class that defines some location.

```
class Address {

    private String country;

    private String city;

    //getters and setters

}
```

My task - to collect some information from external sources using XML with different schemas e.g.:

schema1:

```
<someClass>
    <first>John</first>
    <last>Blue</last>
    <location>Country, City, 123456</location>
</someClass>
```

schema2:

```
<someClass>
    <credentials>John Blue</credentials>
    <address>Country, City</p1>
    <p>123456</p>   
</someClass>
```

and so on.

For this task I'm using JAXB and inheritance for each schema, every object I define as @XmlElement with name and this works ok with simple strings and even with location with appropriate @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. But I have problems when parent class has the same element as inherited, but different type, e.g:

```
<someClass>
    <credentials>John Blue</credentials>
    <address>Country, City</p1>
    <p>123456</p>   
</someClass>

class InheritedClass extends SomeClass {

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "address")
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        //do some work to parse string to Address.class
        //also i tried to use XmlJavaTypeAdapter for this method(with Address.class)
        //also i tried to use XmlElementRef for Address.class
        super.setAddress(addressClass);
    }

}
```

When I'm trying to unmarshal such schema JAXB avoid my overridden method and uses parent with null Address object. I've tried such solutions:

- @XmlElementRef
  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html
- static inner @XmlJavaTypaAdapter http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

The main problem that I cannot modify external XML, only adapts it for my purposes. Also, i cannot modify POJO class because it store in DB and a have a lot of external XML's (so a lot of JAXB entities to unmarshal and adapt).

Comment: I do not see any @XmlSeeAlso. Check this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html